# Which algorithm is used for fill sinks in arc hydro tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, hydrology, arc-hydro

How I can get information regarding the % of voids filled using fill sinks in DEM and the algorithm used to fill the voids using arc hydro tools?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between fill algorithm in arcgis hydrology tool and archydro.they are same. You can read about how arcgis fill tool calculate fill [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-fill-works.htm).

The algorithm developed by Jenson and Domingue (1988) is one of the widely used and has been implemented in many GIS and hydrological softwares, such as Arc Hydro Tools (Maidment,2002), GRASS (Neteler and Mitasova, 2008), HEC GEO-HMS (USACE, 2002), TOPOZ (Garbrecht and Martz,1997).

**Reference:** [An effective depression filling algorithm for DEM-based 2-D surface flow modelling](https://www.hydrol-earth-syst-sci.net/17/495/2013/hess-17-495-2013.pdf)

Comment: OK, Thanks for your reply. Actually I am interested to know the algorithm/formula used for fill sink in Arc Hydro tool..??

Comment: @ErRohitSharmaNandavansi . I edited my answer. Please consider the reference.